# LINQ to SQL - Database Design issue

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql

I'm quite new to working on Databases in general, and hope to get your guidance as to what went wrong.

I have 4 tables at hand, currently set-up in this way:

[image]

**Company** - Just an ordinary Company table with certain data in it

**Company_GoodsPackaging** - A reference table for Company, where the information on WHAT kind of goods the company 'does' and what packaging type, for that good, is being done.

**GoodsType** - Basically an enum, values right now are:

> 1 Commodity
>
> 2 Food / feed
>
> 3 Live Animals
>
> 4 Plants
>
> 5 Special cargo
>
> 6 Exceptional

**PackagingType** - Also an enum, values:

> 1 Parcel
>
> 2 Pallet
>
> 3 Container
>
> 4 Bulk
>
> 5 Oversized

**CODE**

In my code-behind of my ASP.NET website I'm doing the following:

I iterate through all GoodsType values, and try to see whether CompanyX (a LINQ Company object) has this value in its table, and if so, what's the Packaging_Type.Description of the value.

The problem I'm having now, is that when I have my Company object, I don't seem to be able to extract its members.

```
var theSource = (from g in Data.GoodsTypes
select new
{
  gvGoodsType = g.Description,
  gvParcels = true,
  gvContainers = curCompany.Company_GoodsPackagings.GoodsType == g.Goods_Type &&
  curCompany.Company_GoodsPackagings.PackagingType1.Description == "Container"
}
```

The relationships are done, everything seems to be correct, but I can't just seem to be able to extract the GoodsType and PackagingType of a Company_GoodsPackaging entry. I know it's a EntitySet.

Where is my DataBase design flawed/Code logic flawed? I have to say, I'm very new to working in DataBases alltogether. Any help/input would be much welcome.

Error I'm getting in VS is

> Error 26  'System.Data.Linq.EntitySet' does not contain a definition for 'GoodsType' and no extension method 'GoodsType' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.Linq.EntitySet' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) *****\Account\MyAccountTransport.aspx.cs    33  8

Comment: can you put all models involve for this design (code for models)?

Answer (score 2):

If I'm not mistaken, Company -> Company_GoodsPackagings is a one to many relationship?

Therefore the property Copmany_GoodsPackagings will be a collection and so you will need to use the Any() function as follows:

```
var theSource = (from g in Data.GoodsTypes
select new
{
  gvGoodsType = g.Description,
  gvParcels = true,
  gvContainers = curCompany.Company_GoodsPackagings.Any(gp => qp.GoodsType == g.Goods_Type && gp.PackagingType1.Description == "Container")
}
```

**EDIT**: It seems that my suggestion to use Any() is not supported by Linq to SQL. Therefore I would suggest that you bring back the whole goods packaging object and then check to see if it has a value or not in order to determine boolean gvContainers:

You can then convert your anonymous type into a concrete class and add the property at the end of the example:

```
var theSource = (from g in Data.GoodsTypes
select new GoodsResult
{
  gvGoodsType = g.Description,
  gvParcels = true,
  gvGoodsPackaging_Container = curCompany.Company_GoodsPackagings.FirstOrDefault(gp => qp.GoodsType == g.Goods_Type && gp.PackagingType1.Description == "Container")
}

public bool gvContainers {
    get { return this.gvGoodsPackaging != null }
}
```

Comment: Hi there, thanks very much for your willingness to help. Indeed, Company -> Company_GoodsPackagings is a One to Many relationship, as one Company can have various entries in that table.

However, using your solution, and Tim S's (THANKS AGAIN GUYS :)) I am now getting this error:

Local sequence cannot be used in LINQ to SQL implementations of query operators except the Contains operator.

Comment: Ahhh sorry, I guess the Any() function is not supported in linq to sql. I will modify my answer with an alternative solution...

Comment: Roysvork, thanks. I'll try your solution soon. I'm ultimately using the results of this LINQ query to DataBind a GridView element on my webpage, but I guess it doesn't really matter. Just thinking how to map the right Column names to the new result. I'll let you know in due time. Thanks so much for your time and effort on this one.

Still, something in the back of my head tells me, that this could be done easier (in terms of the database structure), or am I wrong? :) I like to question myself a lot..

Comment: No problems. You may also consider using entity framework instead of linq to sql if you are not too far along, as it supports more linq methods as per here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738550.aspx

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `curCompany.Company_GoodsPackagings` is a collection of GoodsPackagings (hence the plural and the mention of `System.Data.Linq.EntitySet`). You can't therefore refer directly to a single GoodsType for the Company in this way.

I think you're looking for a way to test each one of the Company's GoodsPackagings against your conditions. To do this you can use the [`Any()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972.aspx) Linq extension method:

```
using System.Linq;

...

gvContainers = curCompany.Company_GoodsPackagings.Any(gp => gp.GoodsType ==
   g.Goods_Type && gp.PackagingType1.Description == "Container")
```